# Find the Interior and Boundary of the set $A = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: z \neq 0 \land -\pi < \operatorname{Arg}(z) < \pi \}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Find the Interior and Boundary of the set $A = \{z\in\mathbb{C}: z \neq 0 \land -\pi < \operatorname{Arg}(z) < \pi \}$ where $\operatorname{Arg}(Z)$ is the principal argument.

My thought process is that the interior of this set is the set itself. Any $z$ not equal to $0$ or any z not equal to a negative real number will be contained in the set $A$.

However, I am not quite sure about the boundary. My thought process was that the boundary condition is the negative $x$-axis and $z = 0$, but I am not confident in this answer. Sketching the graph of this set helped me understand the interior of A, but it gives me no intuition as to find the boundary.

My main question is whether or not I am on the right track for both the boundary and interior of the set. If anyone could give me some feedback or advice on this problem, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $A$ is an open set, and therefore $\mathring A=A$ indeed.

You you are right about the boundary too. Clearly, $\overline A=\Bbb C$, and therefore$$\partial A=\overline A\setminus\mathring A=\Bbb C\setminus A=(-\infty,0].$$